# How to print one message from a loop within a condition?

Tags: php, for-loop

Let's say I have this loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    if($i > 4){
        echo 'Greater Than 4.' . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

The previous loop will output the following:

```
Greater Than 4.
Greater Than 4.
Greater Than 4.
Greater Than 4.
Greater Than 4.
Greater Than 4.
```

As the condition is true 6 times.

What I want to do is to print this message only once so the output from the same loop and condition will be :

```
Greater Than 4.
```

I think this could be achieved by using a variable and give it this value at a specific point , But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Simply, say `if($i == 5)`

Comment: @SaidbakR , I want the condition to be executed 6 times as it is but outputs one message

Comment: Checkout the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it will be like your code expect that you print the message once:

```
$msg = 'There is no greater than 4';
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    if($i > 4){
        $msg =  'Greater Than 4.' . '<br/>';
        // Make any additional required code here...
    }
}

echo $msg;
```

;

Answer (score 0):

```
$run_once = true;
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    if($i > 4 AND $run_once){
        echo 'Greater Than 4.' . '<br/>';
        $run_once = false;
    }
}
```

you could also use `if ($i == 4)`

EDIT:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
  if($i > 4){
    if($i == 4){
      echo 'this runs only once';
    }
    echo 'this runs every time';
  }
}
```

Comment: But this will run the condition once , I want to run it the same 6 times but output one message , Is that possible ?

Comment: @kevin you need 2 if statements then. Check my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :)

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
echo ($i>4 && !isset($rslt))?$rslt='Greater Than 4.':'';
}
```

Or, you can loop first
then print the result
like this

```
$bucket = '';
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    $bucket = ($i>4)?'Greater Than 4.':$bucket;
}
echo $bucket;
```

Hmmmm, I guess you case like this :D

```
$bucket = $condition = '';
$flag = 1;
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    if($i>4){
       $bucket = 'Greater Than 4. <br>';
       $condition .= "Proses :{$flag}<br>";
       $flag++;
       //more condition process 6 times
    }
}
echo $condition;
echo $bucket;
```

Or like this :D

```
$j=1;
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    if($i>4){
       if($i<=5){
          echo 'Greater Than 4. <br>';
       }
       echo 'Proses '.($j++).'<br>';
       //more condition process 6 times
    }
}
```

Or, using the short hand

```
for($i= $j =0;$i<=10;$i++){
  if($i>4){
     echo ($i<=5)?'TheGreater Than 4. <br>':false;
     $j++;
     echo "Process number : {$j} <br>";
  }
}
```